# shift array by k

Tags: java

i am working on a small java program, its very basic and one of my functions shifts the alphabet by a given key. i have got it working, but its shifting the wrong way, how can i make it shift the other direction?

```
public static char[] ourAlphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};


    public  char[] shiftAlphabet(int key) {

            int length = ourAlphabet.length;

            char[] result = new char[length];

            for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result[(i+key+26)%length] = ourAlphabet[i];
            }

            return result;
    }
```

Im guessing its very simple, but its confused me!

For example;
 with a key 19 produces;
hijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg

when is should produce;
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS

Comment: Have you tries replacing `+key` by `-key`?

Comment: which way is it shifting now and which way do you want it to shift?

Comment: Note that you could limit yourself to using the ourAlphabet array by saving and swapping values (like in sorts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you use `result[(i-key+26)%length] = ourAlphabet[i];`

However, if length != 26 this would still give a wrong result.

I would therefore replace the 26 by length;

```
result[(i-key+length)%length] = ourAlphabet[i];
```

Comment: Indeed. Hardcoding values is a bad practice.

Answer (score 8):

Change to:

```
result[i] = ourAlphabet[(i+key)%length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] ourAlphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};


public  char[] shiftAlphabet(int key) {

        int length = ourAlphabet.length;

        char[] result = new char[length];

        for (int i=0; i < length; i++)
        {
            ourAlphabet[(i+key+26)%length] = result[i];
        }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: The chars in `result` have not been initialized.

Comment: This will probably overwrite characters. A temporary variable would be needed in the for loop.